# Building a 5x6 Dynamic HTML Table

Tags: php, html, dynamic, html-table

I'm trying to build a table that is 5x6 dynamically using PHP. Right now I'm getting my table to be 1x30. I'm probably missing an if statement or something but just can't figure it out. A little help would be great.

```
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product") 
 or die(mysql_error());
 $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
 print "<table border cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 Print "<tr><td>".$info['name'] . "  <br /><img src=".$info['pictureURL'] . " /></td></tr>"; 
 }

print "</table>";
```

Here is a Demo of what it looks like http://nova.it.rit.edu/~mpb8676/FinalProject/compare.php

Comment: I didn't know they were teaching php in classes.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Yes james. I am having a little trouble with it. Never had to format table data before. After looking at some examples that people put below I get it now.

Comment: Was only asking because there is a homework tag.  I was going to add it but wasn't 100% sure.  Adding the homework tag lets people know you're learning and should lead to more indepth explanations.

Comment: oh ok yeah it is homework. Sorry didn't know there was a tag for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing a new row for each record with this line:

```
Print "<tr><td>".$info['name'] . "  <br /><img src=".$info['pictureURL'] . " /></td></tr>";
```

If you want a 5x6 table, then you'll have to add in a column counter:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product") 
or die(mysql_error());
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
print "<table border cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
$numCols = 5;   // Max number of columns
$colCount = 0;  // Current column count (the counter)
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
    if ($colCount == 0) {
        Print "<tr>";
    }

    Print "<td>".$info['name'] . "  <br /><img src=".$info['pictureURL'] . " /></td>";

    $colCount++;

    if ($colCount >= $numCols) {
        Print "</tr>";
        $colCount = 0;
    }
}

print "</table>";
```

There are definitely more efficient ways to go about this, but I tried to keep your code in tact so you'd better understand what your issue was.

Comment: Thank you Maniac. This deffinitly made me realize what I was doing wrong. I knew I was only using one td but had a brain cramp when trying to figure out a way to dynamically create more.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need more td's:

```
  Print "<tr><td>".$info['name'] . "</td><td><img src=".$info['pictureURL'] . " /></td><td>and</td><td>so</td><td>on</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat the `<tr>` specially. Right you're outputting a single celled row for every result in your query. Instead, you need:

```
$cells_printed = 0;
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
   if ($cells_printed % 6 == 0) {
      echo '</tr><tr>'; // start a new row
   }
   echo '<td>blahblahblah</td>';
   $cells_printed++;
}
```

This'll only print the `<tr>` tags when the cell you're on is an even multiple of 6, indicating you've hit the end of the line.

You'll need some extra special casing to handle the very first row printed, so you don't have a dangling `</tr>` at the start of your table, but this should be enough to get you started. You'll also need special case handling for the last row, so you properly close the row even if it's not a "6th" cell being printed at that point.